# Cannot redeclare RecursiveCategories() Error

Tags: php, function

I have this php script:

```
<?php $categories = $this->requestAction('categories/topmenu');
    function RecursiveCategories($array)
    {
        if (count($array))
        {
            foreach ($array as $category)
            {
                if (count($category['children']))
                {
                    echo '<li >';
                    echo '<a href="/v-n/'.$category['Category']['id'].'-'.$category['Category']['slug'].'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">';
                    echo '<div class="sub-menu">'.$category['Category']['name'].'</div>';
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<div class="tn-gnavsub">'; 
                    echo '<div class="gnavsub">'; 
                    echo '<ul class="menufix">'; 
                    RecursiveCategories($category['children']);
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</li>'; 
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="/v-n/'.$category['Category']['id'].'-'.$category['Category']['slug'].'"> '.$category['Category']['name'].'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }

    }
?>
<?php RecursiveCategories($categories); ?>
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare RecursiveCategories() (previously declared in :36) in... on line 64

Comment: Did you include a php file?

Comment: yes include a php file

Comment: You may include the file more than one time, that is may be the problem

Comment: I do not know how to fix it ( sorry I  can not speak english)

Comment: Please share your full code.

Comment: you can please download http://www.mediafire.com/download/6gfdh5u63f084ff/header.ctp

Answer (score 0):

You have included the same function definition via Include statement or some other file, so that's why you got this problem. 
use the following :

```
   if (!function_exists('RecursiveCategories')) {
       function RecursiveCategories($array)
       {
        //code goes here
       }
   }
```

Recommended: add all functions inside a lib file and use include_once command to include the lib.php file.